# Memcached status returning "memcached dead but pid file exists"

Tags: memcached

When I want to see the status of memcached I run `service --status-all` but I get this multiple times "memcached dead but pid file exists" when it lists memcached.

It seems to me that this means memcached needs some cleaning up.   How can I remove those messages about the old pid file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your distro, .pid files will either be located in memcached's working directly (like `/etc/memcached`) or in `/var/run`.

Answer (score 1):

I got this message when memcached has been started under the wrong user account. Killing the old process and restarting it correctly fixed it.

```
[matt@vm]# service memcached status
memcached dead but pid file exists
[matt@vm]# ps aux | grep memcached
roland   24038  0.0  0.0 349780  ... memcached ... -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
[matt@vm]# sudo kill -9 24038

[matt@vm]# service memcached start
Starting memcached:                     [  OK  ]
[matt@vm]# ps aux | grep memcached
memcached   21159  0.0  0.0 330852 ... memcached ... -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
[matt@vm]# service memcached status
memcached (pid  21159) is running...
```

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to do this? `service memcached restart`

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting the pid file, but then would get "subsys locked" error. So I actually had to reboot and the memcached would work fine

Answer (score 0):

I got this message and I fixed it doing this:

`> ps aux | grep memcached`

copied the pid and pasted it on the memcached pid location file:

`> echo 2600880 > /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid`

then it worked

`> service memcached status
Se está ejecutando memcached (pid  2600880)...`